Is it possible to send a sms text to someone’s iPhone and make it appear that they replied to a number that they did not reply to?
I received a text from a number in my iMessages and then synced with iCloud and therefore showed up on my iPhone that I do not recognize. The strange thing is that there is no conversation thread. The only text showing looks like it came from my phone replying back to them saying Hi with an emoji after the Hi. It is very odd because it looks like it was me who replied but I did not. And there was no prior message before this Hi, only the Hi coming from my end.
Is it possible to send a text to someone and make it appear that they replied to this unknown number?


Why is this tagged iPhone when you’re showing messages on macOS?

Because I deleted the message on my iphone, but icloud was synced with my mac. So you are seeing synced sms texts in imessage on my mac.

This message was sent from your device or another device logged into your iMessage. One of three scenarios:

A virus/malware somehow compromised your computer (to what end, unclear)
Someone sent the message on your device or logged in with your account and sent it from another device (this triggers an alert: "XYZ device added to your account")
You need to visit the doctor because you're forgetting things

I would guess #2 is most likely

Number 3 is hilarious and trust me I have thought I was losing my mind lol. Not yet though thankfully!

Yeah number 2 seems the most likely but difficult to prove anything for sure. I found this as well: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6202259?sortBy=best


Is it possible to send a text to someone and make it appear that they replied to this unknown number?

Nothing in your image makes it appear a reply came from your phone. You’re reading things into this SPAM message where nothing actually exists.
But, keep in mind that scammers will use all sorts of tricks to get you to engage with them from spoofing the phone number to variants of the “ILoveYou” virus (winking and kissing emoji) that took down the Internet in the 90s.
Finally, that wasn’t an SMS message but rather an iMessage.  As an iMessage, it can use more than just your phone number to reach you.  It can use your AppleID, any of several email addresses or your phone number(s) - multiple numbers if your using dual SIMs

The fact that the message is blue, not gray, and is on the right, absolutely indicates that it was sent from OP's account.

@AAM111, I never said it came from another account.  I said there’s nothing to indicate it’s a reply

yes, right hand side and blue is a reply from my iphone (or iMessage from my macbook from compromised apple ID) to the sender. It also says Delivered which is the norm for iphone text replies. It possible to forge this kind of reply: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6202259?sortBy=best.

I think the OP is using "reply" to mean outgoing message. Since it's not a number they know, they assumed it was somehow triggered by an incoming message, hence a reply to that.
